# Как прочитать загруженный файл в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, json, acf

Создаю, сайт на wordpress, нужна возможность загрузить в админ панель файлик(json) и уже внутри самой темы работать с информацией в нем. Используется разширение ACF, в котором есть возможность загрузки файла. Может посоветуете какоето разширение для этого, буду очень признателен.

Comment: не понятно зачем какоето расширение, для чего конкретно грузится файл? создавать, обновлять посты? в любом случае можно обойтись без расширений если этото чтото слишком специфичное.

Comment: Никакого расширения под такие уникальные (и к тому  неизвестные задачи - что значит "работать с информацией", какой, для чего и тд) не может быть в принципе. А ACF вообще для других вещей.

Comment: необходимо прочитать файл для настройки некоторых блоков

Comment: Зачем файлом и ещё и загрузкой через ACF??? Не понимаю. Почему не сделать страницу настроек или посредством настроек для рубрик, категорий или всех постов/записей? В одном месте хранить кучу данных... а рационально ли? Опять же, пропал файл или в него запихнут непотребное?

Comment: Нужно для большого количества разных сайтов, на одной и той же теме, тогда контентщикам будет проще загрузить на кучу сайтов контент